# Windows form how to use other function call back chart information

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, charts

Firstly the button click function can successfully create the candlestick chart and get back the count number.

```
//MyForm.h
private: System::Void load_rt_chart_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

  String^ Stime = "09:00";

  for(int sIndex=0; sIndex < 10; sIndex++){
      //insert data to candlestick chart
      rt_chart->Series["Series1"]->Points->AddXY(sTime, 100); //hight
      rt_chart->Series["Series1"]->Points[sIndex]->YValues[1] = 10; //low
      rt_chart->Series["Series1"]->Points[sIndex]->YValues[2] = 20; //open
      rt_chart->Series["Series1"]->Points[sIndex]->YValues[3] = 30; //close
  }
  cout << rt_chart->Series["Series1"]->Points->Count;
  //i can get points of count number here for 10
}
```

But when i use MyForm.cpp to call back the (Myform.h)current_update() function want get the same candlestick chart infor, but the count number always is 0.

```
//MyForm.h
public: System::Void current_update() {

  //i try to get back the chart infor of count number
  cout << rt_chart->Series["Series1"]->Points->Count;
  // the return is 0, i cannot get back any information from rt_chart->Series["Series1"] 
}
```

something am i miss? really need to help, many thanks.

Comment: Both times when you refer to `rt_chart`, are you certain it is the same instance?

Comment: You right, I think this is a problem for that, I had created another class to call the current_update from cpp file. but how can I call the same class to use? Thanks

Comment: You right, I think this is a problem for that, I had created another Form to call the current_update() from cpp file. but how can I call the same From to use? Thanks 

        //MyForm.cpp
        MyForm^ frm = gcnew MyForm();
 frm->current_update(gettime2, getprice, getvolume);

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that set rt_chart to static

```
public: static System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Chart^  rt_chart;
```

the chart will keep the point record everywhere. Thanks Jonathan